# Is Python similar to UnityScript, (JavaScript)?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm wondering if Python is similar to the way JavaScript is used with the Unity3d Game Engine? I know standard JavaScript that manipulates the DOM is very different from how Unity utilizes JS.

Would knowing Python be beneficial to getting started with UnityScript?

Answer (score 3):

Python is very unlike JavaScript, so my vote would be for no.

Comment: Even though JS utilized with Unity is entirely different than DOM structured JS?

Comment: What part of that do you imagine would make it like Python?

Comment: I've ready that the principles of OOP with Python and JS were similar. So I just naturally thought..

Comment: @Twinborn er, no. Some syntax is similar between the two languages, but the object model is perhaps the most different thing of all.

Answer (score 1):

In general, knowing one language will help you learn others, but past that, you're probably better off learning JavaScript itself. I'd suggest looking at [this site](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8329/how-to-get-started-learning-javascript-or-unityscr.html) to get started.

Comment: I personally think the only language that helps when learning JS is asm - because you're always reminded that it could be so much worse ;)